# Why are there neutral supply depots in some Starcraft 2 maps?

Tags: starcraft-2

In some Starcraft 2 maps, there are lowered down supply depots near the ramps of starting locations. I just don't get why they are for. I thought they were a replay thing until I saw them in my own games.

Is there any way to take advantage of that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These exist to make it impossible to block off ramps from below without first investing in the troops necessary to destroy the obstructions.

It's a map feature designed to make it harder to exploit the high ground advantage when you're turtling, or blocking your opponent in with cheap buildings and a small army.

[image: Pylon block]

Comment: I thought it was to prevent walling in on an opponents choke, which denies the critical early expansion that pro Zerg players generally do. There was even a patch to prevent pylons from doing this so easily.

Comment: @Resorath good point. answer updated.

Comment: It doesn't seem so useful to me. A well placed queen can block a ramp. If it does leak add a single zergling and you're in business

Comment: Oh, opponent... Ok ok, that does seem like an abuse

Comment: Edited in a picture to showcase what a neutral supply depot prevents. A pylon block can throw a Zerg quite far back, especially if the protoss builds a cannon behind it. Terrans can use bunkers to the same effect.

Comment: @dbemerlin this is true however i strongly dis-advice this approach unless you have some sort of high ground vision. Otherwise a single roach can simply feast away on some pylons which cost 300 minerals together + 150 for the cannon.